# How to code Bootstrap Accordion only on Smartphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, toggle, accordion

This code works well:

```
<!doctype html> <html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 

<div id="accordion" class="container"> 
<div class="card-deck">

<div class="card"> 
<div class="card-header" id="headingOne" > 
<h3 class="h3_toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Titel 1</h3> 
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion"> 
<div class="card-body">Content 1</div> 
</div>
</div>

<div class="card"> <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo" > 
<h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Titel 2</h3> 
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion"> 
<div class="card-body">Content 2</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

But I want to use this accordion function of Bootstrap ONLY on smartphone. So, I remove all the accordion attributes from my HTML markup and add this in my script.js:

```
(function ($) {
  "use strict";

if (screenwidth <= 768) {
$('.h3_toggle').attr("data-toggle", "collapse").attr("data-target", "#collapseOne").attr("aria-expanded", "true").attr("aria-controls", "collapseOne");
$('#collapseOne').addClass("collapse show");
$('#collapseOne').attr("aria-labelledby", "headingOne").attr("data-parent", "#accordion");    }

})(jQuery);
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the attributes like following and add them according to width like following.

You can use resize function as following: It will trigger if window resize,and also for first init you must check the size.

```html
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body> 

<div id="accordion" class="container"> 
<div class="card-deck">

 <div class="card"> 
  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" > 
   <h3 class="h3_toggleOne">Titel 1</h3> 
  </div>
 <div id="collapseOne"> 
  <div class="card-body">Content 1</div> 
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="card"> 
  <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo" > 
   <h3 class="h3_toggleTwo">Titel 2</h3> 
  </div>
 <div id="collapseTwo"> 
  <div class="card-body">Content 2</div> 
 </div> 
 </div> 
</div> 
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script>

if (screen.width <= 768) { // this will work only one time at first
    addAttributes();
}else {
 removeAttributes();
}

$(window).resize(function() { // this will be work every time screen resize
   if (screen.width <= 768) {
     addAttributes();
 } else {
  removeAttributes();
    }
});

function addAttributes(){
 $('.h3_toggleOne').attr("data-toggle", "collapse").attr("data-target", "#collapseOne").attr("aria-expanded", "true").attr("aria-controls", "collapseOne");
    $('#collapseOne').addClass("collapse show");
    $('#collapseOne').attr("aria-labelledby", "headingOne").attr("data-parent", "#accordion");   
  
    $('.h3_toggleTwo').attr("data-toggle", "collapse").attr("data-target", "#collapseTwo").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("aria-controls", "collapseTwo");
    $('#collapseTwo').addClass("collapse");
    $('#collapseTwo').attr("aria-labelledby", "headingTwo").attr("data-parent", "#accordion");
}
function removeAttributes(){
 $('.h3_toggleOne').removeAttr("data-toggle").removeAttr("data-target").removeAttr("aria-expanded").removeAttr("aria-controls");
 $('#collapseOne').removeClass("collapse show");
 $('#collapseOne').removeAttr("aria-labelledby").removeAttr("data-parent"); 
 $('.h3_toggleTwo').removeAttr("data-toggle").removeAttr("data-target").removeAttr("aria-expanded").removeAttr("aria-controls");
 $('#collapseTwo').removeClass("collapse show");
 $('#collapseTwo').removeAttr("aria-labelledby").removeAttr("data-parent");
}
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Found in the internet. im trying.

Comment: if (screen.width <= 768) { ... not working, unfortunately

Comment: Yes with js you can get with Of Screen with Screen.width

Comment: not working, also tried this:
  if ($(window).width().width < 768) {} ...

but the rest is correct?

Comment: ok. let me look your all file. when I answered there was only js code :)

Comment: thanks <3 :) My HTML markup is fine, am sure, because its working. am just new in js and Jquery, so things like "remove and add" and this stuff. but it should be working yeah?

Comment: Doesnt work, unfortunately :( am sending my new code as a comment to my post

Comment: Hey!  I forgot to make "()" after  "if ($(window).width", so this was the problem. Thank you very much for your help, it was great for my work!

Comment: By the way, If it answered your question can you accept it as answer?

Comment: Can you maybe look at my new question? 